# Does read request in cassandra (with replica 3 and consistency ONE) return the data?

Tags: cassandra, consistency

I have a cluster with 5 node, replica 3, and consistency ONE.
If no node goes down, write success, and no Update commands!

---

if i insert a data (consistency ONE) and then immediately select that data (consistency ONE), when data not exist in other replicas.does it always give me the data (no matter if it is out of date)?

Comment: Please improve your question, it is not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not.

When you select the data with CL ONE the one replica contacted may not have the data yet and will respond NotFound.

If you use write CL ONE you must use read CL ALL to be consistent. Or you can use write CL QUORUM and read CL QUORUM.